# SSO for oracle forms and Java EE

Tags: jakarta-ee, oracle10g, single-sign-on, oracleforms

I've been asked to create a portal from which a user can navigate to several other applications which are created using oracle forms 10g and others created using jsps and servlets, I wanted to ask if this is possible? I've been reading about SSO, am I going in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to find out something almost similar but in my case I am trying to find how to authenticate user using PKI and Oracle Wallet. So right now I am trying to find out how to create and manage SSO through PKI authentication.

For your case, if you using user/password entry you can use SESSION to track legit user once the user is being authenticated for the first time. It would be easier if you are developing Desktop user application. For JSP/Servlet extra precaution need to be taken since it is a server side application that is being accessed from external host. However since the request is about "create a portal" it is more likely you are being asked to develop JSP/Servlet application.

This is the sample tutorial:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19396-01/817-7649/prog_sso.html

Similar topic under stackoverflow:
[How to Implement SSO on existing tomcat web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14950023/how-to-implement-sso-on-existing-tomcat-web-application)